# how to find the particular solution to an inhomogeneous ODE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, systems-of-equations

I need to find the general solution of this equation

> $$y''+4y'+4y=3x e^{-2x}$$

but how do you find the particular solution to this equation?

I found that the characteristic polynomial has the root $r= -2$ so the homogeneous solution is $$y = c_1 e^{-2x} + c_2 xe^{-2x}$$ but then I don't know how to find the particular solution. I tried with $$y_p = (Ax+B)e^{-2x}$$ $$ y_p= (Ax+B)xe^{-2x}$$ $$ y_p= (Ax+B)Ce^{-2x}$$ but nothing is working.

So how to find the particular solution of this ODE?

Comment: Note that we have $y’’+4y’+4y \equiv D^2 +4D+4$. Then the particular integral is: $$\frac{1}{D^2+4D+4}(3xe^{-2x}) = e^{-2x}\frac{3x}{(D-2)^2+4(D-2)+4}$$ Hope you can take it from here.

Comment: Try $x^2\exp(-3x)$ and if that fails $x^3\exp(-2x)$ and if that fails, $x^4\exp(-2x)$ etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Just to make life easier.*

You properly found that the characteristic polynomial has a double root $r=−2$ and you notice that $e^{-2x}$ is also in the rhs of the equation.

So, let $y=u\,e^{-2x}$ which makes the equation to become
$$e^{-2 x} u''=3x\,e^{-2x}\implies u''=3x$$ which is now simpler
$$u''=3x\implies u'=\frac 32 x^2+c_1\implies u=\frac 12x^3+c_1x+c_2\implies y=\left(\frac 12x^3+c_1x+c_2 \right)\,e^{-2x}$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I'm sorry i still don't get it, so you simplify the equation by using substitution to give y, so how do you solve the particular solution? Or y is the particular solution?

Comment: @J.K. Doing that, you just get everything.

Comment: Does this meant that the particular solution is (Ax^2+Bx+C)(exp(-2x)) ?

Comment: Never mind, i got what you meant. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

The RHS function is part of the homogeneous solution, so you can try the particular solution

$$ y_p = Ax^2e^{-2x} $$

Your second guess could also work, but notice that
$$ (Ax+B)xe^{-2x} = Ax^2e^{-2x} + Bxe^{-2x} $$

The term $Bxe^{-2x}$ is already part of the homogeneous solution, so you can discard it. Or even if you don't, it will cancel out after substitution and you're left with an equation only in $A$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! but when i tried it, i still get A=3/2 x. I don't know why i keep on having the x there. and it does not seem right. I'm quite confuse

Comment: I'd suggest you review the method of undetermined coefficient. Or you can show me what you did and I can point out the mistake

Comment: Thanks for the help, really appreciate it. But i found the answer already. Thank you!